# Navbar is weird?

Tags: css

I'm making this navbar in CSS which you can view at http://jsfiddle.net/JVgzW/

The `<a>` tag goes directly down the navbar, and I've tried fixing it by doing `display:block` and stuff like that, but what do I do?

Comment: display: inline-block on your li elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/JVgzW/1/ 
I've added:

```
#navbar li{
    display: inline-block;    
}
```

and `text-align: center;` to your `#navbar`

Comment: Now add line-height: 30px and you will make him the most happy person on earth.

Comment: @Layne it is great privilege to make people happy, isn't it? (especially with a few lines of css :) )

Comment: Thanks but is there any way to space the <a> tag? It kinda looks messy.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could also be using `float: left;`in the `a section`